# JSON.NET dynamic values in json response

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a json response that may or may not contain a value called t_ID. 
Currently I have the following property defined in a class:

```
[JsonProperty("t_ID")]
public string TID { get; set; }
```

If it does not exist I don't want to do anything with it - if it exists in the JSON response I want to deserialize it into the class.

How can this be done?

Comment: Define "I don't want to do anything with it"?

Comment: what happens if u name `TID` to `t_ID`?

Comment: @CodeCaster i mean if t_ID doest not exist - it does not exist (I cant deserialize something that does not exist).

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. If the field is not present in the JSON, the deserialized object will contain the default value for that property.

Comment: The linked solution worked. Thanks. What is the default value ?